# How do you reference a one to many relationship in CRMService?

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I have a custom entity with a one to many relationship (reference, non parental) defined in Dynamics.  I'm using CRMService. I've published my changes and updated the webservice reference in my project.

How do I access this relationship in my code?  How do you use CRMService code to reference a relationship?

I've found some code for many-to-many and understand that is difficult, but what about one to many?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Each one to many relationship has two important bits:

1. A name - this isnt used as often but for example contact has a relationship to account which represents the primary contact for the account, the name of this is "account_primary_contact".
2. A field on the many entity (the foreign key), in the case of the primary contact this is "primarycontactid".

Theres three main things things you can do with a one to many relationship (note, I'm using the late bound entities in my examples here, I will be using the primary contact relationship in my snippets).

**1. Create a link between two records**

Basically you just populate the foreign key with the Id of the thing you want to link to.

```
//Create a contact
Guid contactId = service.Create(new DynamicEntity("contact"));

//Create a lookup which we will use to link the contact and account
Lookup lookup = new Lookup();
lookup.Value = contactId;
lookup.type = "contact";

//Create an account which is linked to the contact record
DynamicEntity account = new DynamicEntity("account");
account["name"] = "Test Account";
account["primarycontactid"] = lookup;
Guid accountId = service.Create(account);
```

**2. Find out what records are linked by those relationships**

So this is a case of creating a QueryExpression which either uses LinkEntities:

```
LinkEntity link = new LinkEntity();
link.LinkFromEntityName = "contact";
link.LinkFromAttributeName = "contactid";
link.LinkToEntityName = "account";
link.LinkToAttributeName = "primarycontactid";
```

Or a ConditionExpression which filters the related records to those linked to your primary record.

```
ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression();
condition.AttributeName = "primarycontactid";
condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
condition.Values = new string [] { contactId.ToString() };
```

Full examples on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928438.aspx).

**3. Break the link between two records**

So this is achieved by setting the foreign key to null.

```
DynamicEntity account = new DynamicEntity("account");
account["primarycontactid"] = null;
service.Update(account);
```